# AnyLogic- how to import a 3D object to AnyLogic

Tags: 3d, anylogic

I have created a 3D object using FREECAD and exported it as a Collada (DAE) file, with the intention of using it as a prop in an AnyLogic animation, I have copied the file into the main folder for the project and into the '3d' folder.

The problem is that I cant seem to find the object in the '3D objects' menu in the Palette. If I'm looking in the wrong place or have imported the file incorrectly please let me know.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place. No need to copy the file anywhere. Instead:

1. drag in a "3D object" into your model as below
   [image]
2. select the file you have in the file selector for the object:
   [image]

View it in a 3D window as usual. Anylogic copies the file for you